# Perilex wall plug and multi switch configuration issues

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I am having a serious issue with my mechanical ventilation system.

I have replaced the old one and bought a new one from the same brand and with the connection (dammm Perilex!).

I thought that the device will work right away but not... thats where the problem started.

I have tried almost all the combinations on perilex plug (while keeping earth and neutral in place all the time) but couldn’t found a working(!) solution with my 3 way switch.

Finally I connected all the wires as mentioned on product manual to the plug.
[image]

The ventilator is not working on neither or the speeds dictated by the 3 way switch.
I have then tried to measure the voltage on different switch positions.

Here is what I found ...
[image]

I was expecting some 0v in respective positions... i.e. 0V for L2, If we select Speed 1 (S1), or 0V for L1 If we select Speed 2 (S2)... but neither of them goes 0v as I always have some voltage on each.

May be thats the reason... may be switch is broken or I am missing a very fundamental point which might be all about how that is being setup in the electric box.

This is current connections of the plug (I couldn't take the fuse down as It cuts the lights .. at least for now. .. )

In summary I have one blue, one green, two black and one brown wires. I have tired make them all visible for everyone with arrows in colours.

[image]

[image]

Finally this is how my main electric box looks like.
Number 8 is the fuse of that plug (as well as almost all the light sources, plugs in the kitchen and some more out power outlets).

I was expecting a bit different fuse (combined one or so...)  as I believe (not sure anything anymore though) that is 3 phase

[image]

What do you think ?

The ventilation system is working ... it is not broken .. as the dealer checked it again ..

by the these are the inputs on the board.
[image]
and the supplied schematics from the manual.

[image]

And this is the current connection of the 3 way switch as well as the connection diagram from the manufacturer

[image]

[image]

I am more or less a handy guy and would like to fix this by my own but that kind of output is unique in Netherlands (where I moved), I have no experience on these and I am really exhausted.

Any help will be appreciated !

thank you

UPDATE :
I started to see very strange behaviour... or I am getting mad.
I have plugged the fan to the same outlet and observed that the fan starts to run .. increases the speed for 3-4 sec.. and stops .. then starts and stops. goes on and on .. ...

If I check the voltages (the switch is on highest setting) L1 is 232V stable, L2 is not stable and around 150s.. and L3 is 230 but gets lower and lower by the speed increases until 160V s where the fan stops. When the fan stops, It jumps to 220v-230v and gradually decreases as an opposite of the fan speed.

It is almost mid night in here.. may be something behaves different on the grid compare to day hours when I don't get 220-230v even for a moment. ...

Something weird is going on..

Comment: A picture of your actual wiring showing both the wires in the plug and to the receptacle would be beneficial. Feel free to [edit] your post to include it.

Comment: Sure.. just did that! hope it helps

Comment: Are the voltage measurements done with the ventilator plugged in? If so, unplug it and measure at the socket alone.

Comment: @TooTea I did both... the one with ventilator plugin is down in the comments below.

Just unplugged and checked again

Speed1 :  L1>135 L2>145 L3>200
Speed2 : L1>180 L2>230 L3>207
Speed3 : L1>230 L2>180 L3>204

are the current readings.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't be fooled by Perilex, this isn't 3-phase.**

Unlike the 'Muricans, who seem to require a dozen or two of different plugs, one for each conceivable purpose, Dutch engineers have come up with the one plug to rule them all, the Perilex. Wisely realizing that there's plenty of situations that call for a mains-voltage grounded plug with more than two working contacts, they have found several different ways to wire a Perilex receptacle/plug:

- As a **three-phase socket for motors** (one neutral + all three phases), protected by a 3-phase breaker (*krachtgroep*)
- As a socket for **two single-phase circuits for cooktopsw** (two neutrals  + two phase conductors), protected by a dual breaker (that *fornuisgroep* you have at the top left of your breaker panel). These two circuits can be fed from the same phase or from two different phases depending on the way your house is wired. The point is that the cooktop doesn't need to care.
- As a **single-phase socket for central ventilation** (one neutral + one phase + two control wires for selecting the speed), protected by an ordinary single breaker.

If you look at the wiring diagram in your question, there's a single "L" (phase) wire entering from the bottom, connected to the "L3" contact which supplies power to the ventilation system. "L1" and "L2" are just control signals telling the ventilation system on what speed to run.

Now, the confusing voltages you measured are due to the L1/L2 contacts being left disconnected (floating) when not in use. Your multimeter is likely just picking up stray voltage induced onto the floating wires. (Or flowing back from the ventilation system if you measured this with it connected.)

There's one 230 V entry in each L1 and L2 column, which shows that your speed selector switch is working properly (apart from the fact that it looks like the "L" and "M" speeds are swapped).

The trouble is likely in the connection of the L3 contact. That's supposed to provide 230 V to power the system, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. You'll need to investigate a bit to figure out what is going on here. If you have a contact voltage tester (one that has a small light in it that lights up when you touch a live wire), try that on L3. There might be a loose connection somewhere or some other issue.

Comment: This is correct. Low and Medium speeds are not achieved by delivering lower voltages.  They are achieved by signaling on different wires.  Your best bet is to read the manual and wiring diagrams that came with your new unit and follow the instructions carefully.   If it doesn't work, modify your question so that it shows those instructions and diagrams, how you interpreted them to wire your installation, and what works or doesn't work accordingly.

Comment: I don't have the same respect as you do for the engineers who designed to use *extra* high voltage wires for signaling.  If they did it on the *existing* wires that would be way cool.  But if they demand extra wires to be run, why not separate the signalling and use low voltage wires and switches?  In fact a lot of these units have that ALSO.

Comment: @TooTea thanks for the clarifications and details. you are right about non 230V measurements as they are always floating. If they are 230V and they are rock solid.
 
I did some additional measurements but not from the plug but from the input of the ventilation system. (added the image on the original post) 
The numbers are changed this time.

Now what I am seeing is 
 L1 L2 L3
S1 106 110 150
S2 155 230 155
S3 230 155 155

Yes, I don't see 230 on L3 (brown in my case) at any time.
What would be the reason for this ? Is switching the cable can change this or it is not healthy at all?

Comment: There are four relevant wires in your last photo.  White, Black, Brown, Blue.  One of them is Live.   In the switch that one should be open, or connected to ONE of the others.  You haven't given us enough info to know which wire is L, L2, L3.   If I guess that brown is L and blue is N, then the switch must either connect brown to black or white, or leave it open.  The wires must be connected to the switch so that the switch does that.  It's not obvious how to get that right ... the four connections look similar and symmetric.  Use the instructions, measure continuity not voltage.

Comment: Remember this isn't just a Perilex *socket*.  There is a switch attached to it, that shorts together certain terminals.  The orientation of that switch with respect to the colors of the four wires, matters.  We can't guess this.

Comment: Isn't there a knob you can turn that affects what is connected to what?  In your documentation, the idea of L, L2, L3, and N should be associated with the four colored wires and/or the pins of their white wiring harness in your last picture.  They may even be labelled that way on the back of the circuit board, which may be easy to look at?  Is it held in by that orange clip?

Comment: Hello @jay613, When I connect the plug, the white wire is connected to one of the blacks (with the one blue tape on the first image).
To summary. The current connection is,
L1->black with blue tape on the plug->while wire on the circuit board
L2-> black on the plug -> black on the circuit board
L3-> brown on the plug -> brown on the circuit board.  .. the rest (earth and neutral are same). 
I always though that brown is live and the other two (blacks) are the controlling the speed.. so I believe that L3 (brown) should give 230V all the time while the others switch to 230V respectively.

Comment: @jay613 You can find the connection diagram on the user manuel attached the questions as well.

Comment: Ok now I understand and that is good.  Where/why does the white wire become black?  You should always have 230V on L3-N, in all switch positions.  If the switch is in M position there should be 230V on L2-N.  In High, on L1-N.   In low position there is no defined voltage on L2 and L1.  I think that is how you already understand it.  But your table shows that L3 is not always 230V.  This answer already noted that long ago ... maybe a loose connection somwehere.

Comment: Check at the white terminal block in your last picture, measure Brown-Blue.  Is that ALWAYS 230V in all switch positions?  If it is not, unplug the white plug, and try simulating the switch with jumpers, then taking the same measurements.  Be careful, turn all power off while you play with those pins.

Comment: @jay613 yes, now we are on the same page :) .. And yes. ... the brown cable, which connected to L3 never gets 230V at least in my current configuration. The others gets 230V respectively.. but not al the time as well... So I dont have any wire with 230V all the time. I think thats the problem .. If I have one wire with 230v all the time, I will use this on L3 and control the others .. but not in my case.. 

and I believe the brown should always have 230V ... and I dont know where it comes from ... and where to check for a possible loose wire issue...  the main electrical box is sealed...

Comment: @jay613 I am not sure about jumpers (I guess you mean dip switches, right ? I have some on the circuit board but mainly used for the suction rate of the ventilator. Should I?

Comment: 1) If you use a meter to measure brown-blue at the circuit board with the switch installed and switched to different positions, do you always get 230V?  2) Where and why does white become black?

Comment: @jay613 I tried a couple of settings but neither of them boosted the brown-blue to 230V range.. thats why the device not working with that configuration. I have two blacks and brown on the wall plug. The cable on the unit has one black, one brown and  one white from factory... I checked them and  the white one is mapped to black one on L1. The others are matching. I think all the problem relies on why I dont get 230 on brown all the time. .. or lets say neither of the blacks as well. I should measure 230 one one of the cable all the time and should use this on L3 .. Thats where I got stuck...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131128/discussion-between-atoprak-and-jay613).